# Click not working on combo-box down arrow button karate UI testing

Tags: karate

I tried clicking on down arrow button for a Combo Box (Select is not available. Its a React JS application and once I click on arrow button only list shows selection items)  using below karate command but click not happened in application and no error displayed. [The same xpath worked in selenium click command,and showing unique item on Inspect search]

And waitFor("//div[@id='root']/div/div[3]/main/div/div[3]/div[2]/div")
And click("//div[@id='root']/div/div[3]/main/div/div[3]/div[2]/div")

Note: Then I tried below command
And assert('//div[@id='root']/div/div[3]/main/div/div[3]/div[2]/div').exists

and got error 
javascript evaluation failed: assert('//div[@id='root']/div/div[3]/main/div/div[3]/div[2]/div').exists, :1:19 Expected , but found root
assert('//div[@id='root']/div/div[3]/main/div/div[3]/div[2]/div').exists

Comment: This is the html<div aria-hidden="true" class=" css-tlfecz-indicatorContainer">
 <svg height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" class="css-19bqh2r">
  <path d="M4.516 7.-0.406 02  0-4.0.436-1.17 0-1.615z"></path>
 </svg>
</div>

Comment: I request you to submit it in the format given in my comment - it will really help us, and fix this for all future users. if it is too difficult, at the very least - try to find us a public example

Answer (score 1):

It would really help us if you follow this process, it is simple and should not take much time for you to give us a small snippet of static HTML (or you can mix react if really needed).

https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test

EDIT: you also seem to have mis-matched single and double-quotes in your code.

Also note that you should be able to fire a JS event or click by using the `script()` API. See this example: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#script

So this is an alternate approach to be able to overcome any tricky situation that comes up.

Comment: I gone through the readme of https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/examples/ui-test . But actually I am Sorry ,I was not able to understand what we are trying to do. also Run as Junit was not showing. And how scrit() can be used for clicking something.

Comment: @Sumith you can use `script()` to set the value, and the docs also say how to fire an event if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-core#script